# PHP string to Date and Time

Tags: php, datetime

I have the following string: `2010-04-08T12:46:43+00:00`

I want to convert that to:

8th April 2010 @ 12:46

Is that easy enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yep. use [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) + [date()](http://php.net/date)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at strtotime to create a UNIX timestamp from your time string, and then use date($format, $UNIXtimestamp); to create a normal date again:

```
$Timestamp = strtotime("2010-04-08T12:46:43+00:00");
echo date("your time format", $Timestamp);
```

You can look up the specific characters for the time format from PHP.net

Comment: and as always stackoverflow feed newbies with complete solutions so they ask their manual questions more and more.

Comment: The "complete solutions" get accepted, folks want points so provide "complete solutions" to get accepted…

Answer (score 2):

Here you go.

**EDIT :** Exactly as you needed

**Code:**

```
$time_value = strtotime("2010-04-08T12:46:43+00:00");
$date_in_your_format = date( 'jS F Y @ g:i', $time_value);  
echo $date_in_your_format;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).